# Different formalizations of fine structural concepts

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

**EDIT I**:
After contacting one of the authors of the "Fine Structure" article in the handbook, they told me that the way Mitchell and Steel develop fine structure, is a bit different from how Jensen, Zeman and Schindler do it. They however remarked that there are translation procedures between them and there is a bit on this in the Mitchell-Steel book. I took a look at that and although a bit enlightening, it didn't make the whole picture clear, as they only prove that $r{\bf\Sigma}^{\mathcal{M}}_{n+1}$ subsets are the same as ${\bf\Sigma}_1$ subsets in an appropriate place(in the "Appendix to \$$2$"); but for me, that doesn't make it clear how all the lemmas and theorems carry over.

For now I have decided to ignore these issues and continue reading the article, but I would appreciate any references or answers which outline some clear transfer process.

---

A while ago I had decided to start studying inner model theory. And my main goal was to at least study J. Steel's "An outline of inner model theory". But then I realized I needed to learn a bit of fine structure, so I started reading the fine structure article in the handbook. Now that I have finished studying that and having returned to Steel's article, I realized that the definitions they use are a bit different and for example they define the projecta and standard parameters using cores, instead of reducts and their definition of solidity and soundness seems a bit different at first sight. (Also the $\Sigma_0$ code thingy is also a mystery to me, and I don't know why they don't use the ppm itself.)[The definitions in Steel's article are the ones in the sections $2.3$ and $2.4$ and the definitions in the fine structure article, are in the chapters $2$, $5$, $6$ and $7$.]

So I would like to know: Should I ignore these discrepancies and try to go with these new definitions? Or are there other references I should study beforehand? Or maybe is there a straightforward manner to unify these seemingly different definitions and they are equivalent after all?

Since the definitions are quite lengthy, I think it will clutter the question to list all of them and their counterparts in both texts, so I have decided to omit them. If needed, I will delete this post and edit in the definitions and I'll repost.

As an example, the definition of the first projectum goes like this:

> (The "Fine Structure" article): Let $M$ be some acceptable $J$-structure, then the $\rho_1(M)$ is defined to be the least $\rho \in \mbox{On}$ such that $P(\rho)\cap{\bf\Sigma}^M_1 \not \subseteq M$.

> (The "An Outline of Inner Model Theory" aricle): First let $\mathcal{M} = \mathcal{J}^{\overrightarrow{E}}_\alpha$ be a ppm; then the $\Sigma_0$ code of $\mathcal{M}$, or $C_0(M)$ is the $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{N}$ given by:
> $1$. if $M$ is passive, then $\mathcal{N}$ has universe $J^{\overrightarrow{E}}_\alpha$, $\dot{E}^{\mathcal{N}} = \overrightarrow{E}|\alpha$, $\dot{F}^{\mathcal{N}} = \emptyset$ and $\dot{\mu}^{\mathcal{N}} = \dot{\nu}^{\mathcal{N}} = \dot{\gamma}^{\mathcal{N}} = 0$. 
> $2$. if $M$ is active of types $I$ or $II$, then $\mathcal{N}$ has universe $J^{\overrightarrow{E}}_\alpha$, $\dot{E}^{\mathcal{N}} = \overrightarrow{E}|\alpha$, $\dot{F}^{\mathcal{N}} = E^*_\alpha$ and $\dot{\mu}^{\mathcal{N}} = \mu^{\mathcal{M}}$ and $\dot{\nu}^{\mathcal{N}} = \nu^{\mathcal{M}}$ and $\dot{\gamma}^{\mathcal{N}} = \gamma^{\mathcal{M}}$. 
> $3$. if $M$ is active of type $III$, then setting $\nu = \nu({E_\alpha})$, $\mathcal{N}$ has universe $J^{\overrightarrow{E}}_\nu$, $\dot{E}^{\mathcal{N}} = \overrightarrow{E}|\nu$, $\dot{F}^{\mathcal{N}} = E_\alpha|\nu$ and $\dot{\mu}^{\mathcal{N}} = \mu^{\mathcal{M}}$ and $\dot{\nu}^{\mathcal{N}} = \dot{\gamma}^{\mathcal{N}} = 0$.
> Def. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a ppm; then the first projectum of $\mathcal{M}$, $\rho_1(\mathcal{M})$ is defined to be the least $\rho \in \mbox{On}$ such that $P(\rho)\cap{\bf\Sigma}^{C_0(\mathcal{M})}_1 \not \subseteq C_0(\mathcal{M})$.

The language $\mathcal{L}$ is defined before the definition and just adds the symbols in the definition to $\mathcal{L}_\in$.

Now the dependence of the definition on $C_0(\mathcal{M})$ makes this definition confusing for me, further, the iterated versions, are done inside cores instead of reducts, and make the definition unfamiliar to me. This is one of the discrepancies of I was talking about.

Comment: Just wait until you see how Menachem Magidor develops inner model theory.

Comment: Nice. Another rabbit hole to add to the arsenal! Asking just out of curiousity, do you have a reference for Magidor's approach?

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. He gave two courses about it a few years back, it wasn't very easy to follow, and he tried to create a mixed approach "for the sake of us" so that we could "communicate with other people on these topics".

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. But on the plus side, I don't have more material to ultra-confuse myself! :)

Comment: If you really want to, you can dig through his paper with a proof of the covering lemma.